# "Encoding" algorithm giving different result in separate method

Tags: java, algorithm, encoding

So i set out to make a little "encoding" program that uses a simple algorithm and so far it all works. i came up with the algorithm, and then found the inverse of it to "decode" the given String.

How it works is that in command line you do "java Diver *lock* *message* *password*". It then takes the ascii values and runs it through the algorithm Z_n = (X_n + Y_n) / 2, giving you an "encoded" string that can then be used in the program arguments on start as "java Driver *unlock* *code* *password*". It takes these values and runs them through X_n = 2Z_n - y_n.

These algorithms work when simply using the lock portion, and i've put the same process at the end of lock that happens in the unlocking process, yet when trying only the locking process, the output is incorrect.

Here's a little snippet as to how i believe it is working

lock Oliver Chipper

unlock ĤƨƤǌƪƮä Chipper

x = message, y = password, z = code

x & y  = z

z & y  = x

I have a feeling that it has to do with the command line not taking in the symbols that are used as output, but a thorough explanation of what i've done would be great... Thank you!

```
public class Driver {

private static int[] x; //Message or code
private static int[] y; //Password

public static void main(String[] args) {

    int SIZE = args[1].length() + args[2].length();

    if (args[0].equals("lock")) {
        lock(args, SIZE);

    } else if (args[0].equals("unlock")) {
        unlock(args, SIZE);
    }
}

private static void lock(String[] args, int size) {

    x = new int[size];
    for (int i = 0; i < args[1].length(); i++) {
        x[i] = args[1].charAt(i);                       //Message to ints
    }

    y = new int[size];
    for (int i = 0; i < args[2].length(); i++) {
        y[i] = args[2].charAt(i);                       //Password to ints
    }

    //code
    int[] z = new int[size];
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        z[i] = ((x[i] + y[i]) * 2);                     //Locking algorithm
        System.out.print((char)z[i]);
    }

    System.out.println("\n");

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        System.out.print((char)((z[i] / 2) - y[i]));    //Unlocking algorithm
    }
}

private static void unlock(String[] args, int size) {

    x = new int[size];
    for (int i = 0; i < args[1].length(); i++) {
        x[i] = args[1].charAt(i);                       //Code to ints
    }

    y = new int[size];
    for (int i = 0; i < args[2].length(); i++) {
        y[i] = args[2].charAt(i);                       //Password to ints
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        System.out.print((char)((x[i] / 2) - y[i]));    //Unlocking algorithm
    }
}}
```

Comment: Is integer division `x[i] / 2` what you are wanting i.e. `5/2 == 2`

Comment: Yea @ScaryWombat, thats what i was trying to get at.

Comment: @Topaco Thank you, that clears up a lot of my questions!